# Suma de opciones elegidas en aplicación tipo test Android

Tags: java, android-studio

estoy haciendo una app java con Android Studio del tipo test, consta de varias preguntas, donde en cada una hay varias opciones que tienen un valor distinto, por ej:

Respuesta "a": 0 pts.
Respuesta "b": 1 pts.
Respuesta "c": 2 pts.

Al seleccionar una respuesta, esta se marca y debemos presionar botón siguiente para ir a la pregunta que sigue en otra activity hasta llegar a la ultima pantalla que muestra el resultado total de la suma de las opciones elegidas en el test para luego guardar el resultado final.

El problema viene acá: la app me suma bien las opciones pero **solo** cuando presiono una sola vez el botón de la respuesta elegida y doy siguiente, si yo presiono varias veces ej: "a,b,b,c,a,a" en la misma pregunta antes de dar a siguiente es como que me sigue acumulando y me muestra mal el resultado al final del test, y si yo vuelvo hacia atrás la pantalla en caso de haber presionado mal la opción y luego presiono la que quería en realidad y voy de nuevo hacia la siguiente pregunta también me suma mal.

A continuación les muestro parte del código de las primeras preguntas y la ultima pantalla para ver donde puede estar el fallo, desde ya gracias por leer.

Pregunta 1A:

```
public class pagina1a extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button a1, a2, a3, a4, sig1;
int calificacion=0;
Intent i;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pagina1a);

    i = new Intent(pagina1a.this, pagina1b.class);

    a1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a1);
    a2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a2);
    a3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a3);
    a4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.a4);
    sig1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sig1);

    a1.setOnClickListener(this);
    a2.setOnClickListener(this);
    a3.setOnClickListener(this);
    a4.setOnClickListener(this);
    sig1.setOnClickListener(this);
    sig1.setEnabled(false);



}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.a1:

            calificacion=0;

            a1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF4CAF50"));
            a2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#673AB7"));
            a3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#673AB7"));
            a4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#673AB7"));

            sig1.setEnabled(true);


            break;

        case R.id.a2:
            calificacion=1;

            a2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF4CAF50"));
            a1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#673AB7"));
            a3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#673AB7"));
            a4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#673AB7"));

            sig1.setEnabled(true);


            break;

        case R.id.a3:
            calificacion=2;
            a3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF4CAF50"));
            a2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#673AB7"));
            a1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#673AB7"));
            a4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#673AB7"));


            sig1.setEnabled(true);

            break;

        case R.id.a4:
           calificacion=3;

            a4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF4CAF50"));
            a2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#673AB7"));
            a3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#673AB7"));
            a1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#673AB7"));

            sig1.setEnabled(true);


            break;

        case R.id.sig1:
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    i.putExtra("calificacion", calificacion);
}
```

}

Pregunta 1B:

```
public class pagina1b extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button b1, b2, b3, sig2;
int calificacion=0;
Intent i, recibe;
Bundle b;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pagina1b);
    i=new Intent(pagina1b.this,pagina1c.class);
    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);
    b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b3);
    sig2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sig2);
    sig2.setEnabled(false);


    try {
        recibe=getIntent();
        b=recibe.getExtras();
        calificacion = b.getInt("calificacion");
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Error al obtener datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    b3.setOnClickListener(this);
    sig2.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.b1:
            calificacion+=0;

            b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF4CAF50"));
            b2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#673AB7"));
            b3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#673AB7"));

            sig2.setEnabled(true);

            break;

        case R.id.b2:
            calificacion+=1;

            b2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF4CAF50"));
            b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#673AB7"));
            b3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#673AB7"));


            sig2.setEnabled(true);

            break;

        case R.id.b3:
            calificacion+=2;

            b3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF4CAF50"));
            b1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#673AB7"));
            b2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#673AB7"));


            sig2.setEnabled(true);

            break;

        case R.id.sig2:
            startActivity(i);
            break;





        default:
            break;

    }
    i.putExtra("calificacion", calificacion);
}
```

}

Pregunta 1C:

```
public class pagina1c extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button c1, c2, c3, sig3;
int calificacion=0;
Intent i, recibe;
Bundle b;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pagina1c);
    i=new Intent(pagina1c.this,pagina2.class);

    c1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.c1);
    c2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.c2);
    c3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.c3);
    sig3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sig3);
    sig3.setEnabled(false);


    

    try {
        recibe=getIntent();
        b=recibe.getExtras();
        calificacion = b.getInt("calificacion");
    }catch (Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Error al obtener datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    c1.setOnClickListener(this);
    c2.setOnClickListener(this);
    c3.setOnClickListener(this);
    sig3.setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.c1:
            calificacion+=0;

            c1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF4CAF50"));
            c2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#673AB7"));
            c3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#673AB7"));


            sig3.setEnabled(true);

            break;

        case R.id.c2:
            calificacion+=1;

            c2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF4CAF50"));
            c1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#673AB7"));
            c3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#673AB7"));


            sig3.setEnabled(true);

            break;

        case R.id.c3:
            calificacion+=2;
            c3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF4CAF50"));
            c1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#673AB7"));
            c2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#673AB7"));

            sig3.setEnabled(true);

            break;

        case R.id.sig3:
            startActivity(i);
            break;


        default:
            break;

    }
    i.putExtra("calificacion", calificacion);
}
```

}

Pantalla TOTAL:

```
public class total extends AppCompatActivity {
    Intent i, recibe;
    Bundle b;
    int calificacion = 0;
    Button reg, buscar, guardar;
    TextView resultado;
    TextView nivel, ETdni, ETnombre;
    TextView tvFechaActual;
    ConexionSQLiteHelper conn;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.total);
        conn = new ConexionSQLiteHelper(getApplicationContext(),"bd_pacientes",null,2);
        reg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reg);
        guardar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.guardar);
        resultado = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtResultado);
        nivel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtNivel);
        ETdni = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDniPacienteTotal);
        ETnombre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtPacienteTotal);


        i = new Intent(total.this, MainActivity.class);
        try {
            recibe = getIntent();
            b = recibe.getExtras();
            calificacion = b.getInt("calificacion");
            resultado.setText("" + calificacion);

            if (calificacion >= 0 && calificacion < 4) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Gravedad del ictus: Leve", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                nivel.setText("Leve");

            } else if (calificacion >= 4 && calificacion < 16) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Gravedad del ictus: Moderado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                nivel.setText("Moderado");
            } else if (calificacion >= 16 && calificacion < 25) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Gravedad del ictus: Grave", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                nivel.setText("Grave");
            } else if (calificacion >= 25) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Gravedad del ictus: Muy grave", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                nivel.setText("Muy Grave");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error al obtener datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        reg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });




    }
```

Comment: Si cada vez que pulsas, sumas lo que tienes, pues obviamente si pulsas varias veces te sumará varias veces. Tendrás que controlar que una vez pulsado, ya no pueda pulsar otra opción. O que en vez de guardar la calificación ya sumada, guardes la que vas a sumar y solo la sumes cuando pulsa siguiente.

Comment: Hola, lo de no poder presionar otra opción una vez presionada una ya lo hice, pero me dijeron que así no porque si se confunden en una pregunta ya no te dejaría cambiarla en caso de error y debería reiniciar el test en lugar de corregir en el momento. ¿Cómo podría modificar el código que tengo ahora con la opción esa de que guarde lo que va a sumar y solo sume al pulsar siguiente? estoy medio perdido

Comment: Guardando en una variable lo que vas a sumar según seleccione. Esa variable cambiará cada vez que pulses. Al final cuando pulsas el botón siguiente, tomas esa variable con ese valor y se lo sumas a la cuenta actual y se la pasas a la siguiente actividad. Solo cuando pulsa siguiente. Los demás botones no alteran la cuenta, solo actualizan lo que van a sumar.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Centrate en un problema a la vez.. porque si no, sera imposible responder, porque cada vez que te respondan algo, vas a encontrar otro problema nuevo...